# MediaWiki - ERROR: 20024 (The given path misformatted or contained invalid characters)

Tags: windows, special-characters, mediawiki

I am running mediawiki in xampp on windows and keep getting the error:

ERROR: 20024 (The given path misformatted or contained invalid characters)

Is there a workaround or software bundle that can be installed to eliminate this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting MediaWiki to use the article names as parameters instead of using them as file names?

On your LocalSettings.php

`$wgArticlePath = $wgScriptPath.'/index.php?title=$1';`